# Inability to run python 3 scripts in both IDLE mode and from command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python using the book "Learn Python: think like a computer scientist",  however after I downloaded and installed Anaconda 3, I ran into some problems while trying to run scripts from the IDLE mode. (In fact for over a week, I 've been trying to resolve the issue.)  There is a function  the book said we should write and test, I saved the script in the file print_twice_cat.py. However, each time I try to run the script, I just get this error message: ======== RESTART: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\Scripts\print_twice_cat.py ========. (Other functions saved as scripts produce the same output, with the only change in the error message being in the .py file name.)
   Also, if  i include a print statement (eg print ('spam')) in the script, I would get an output for the print statement, but no output for any function included in the script such as the above. 
      I also googled around and found some sites suggested adding the python location in C drive to the path variable. In my path variable, I had: "ipts;C:\users\user\Anaconda3\Library\bin" (without the quotes) so I added: ;C:\Python35  at the end, but I still got the same RESTART message only.
After googling further (on several sites, including the stackoverflow site), I decided on a work-around of running the Python scripts from the windows command prompt. With the ;C:\Python35 from above still in my path variable, I typed python  at the  C:\Users\USERS> prompt and then in the python environment, I typed the name of the file (print_twice_cat.py) at the prompt, but what I got was this error message: "NameError: 'print_twice_cat' is not defined."
       I also searched on the stackoverflow site and got this command to use to run a Python 3 in idle mode from command linem: $ python3 -m idlelib -r your_script.py  But when I typed it, the message I got was : Syntax error: invalid syntax.
       Also my Anaconda python version is Python 3.5.1 and my operating system is windows 7, bit 32. I would really appreciate any suggestion/suggestions that would help me resolve these 2 issues, as they 're really frustrating my learning efforts. And furthermore it would help other users who might face  related challenges.
     Also kindly find below the contents of the script file in question:

```
> def print_twice(bruce):
>     print(bruce)
>     print(bruce)
> 
> 
> def cat_twice(part1, part2):
>     cat = part1 + part2
>     print_twice(cat)
> 
> 
>   line1 = 'Bing tidddle'
>   line2 = 'tiddle bing'
>   cat_twice = (line1,line2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This

===========RESTART=============

Thing just means by this point the output on the screen is the output of your code stored in the file `print_twice_cat.py` . It's not an Error.
Since your learning python, you couldn't know that functions only define code, the don't do anything unti they're called.(So they don't print all alone, too)

For Example I'm writing a function to print LaLaLa twice on the screen:

```
    def myfunction():
        print('LaLaLa')
        print('LaLaLa')

    myfunction()
```

The first three lines don't do anything but defining the function ´myfunction´. The fourth statement calls the function and so the code defined in the functions body

Comment: First of, thanks for taking the time to help me out, but please could you provide more clarifications? The script in question actually has 2 functions defined in it, but some arguments were also provided for the second function, just before it was called in the script. In that case, wouldn't it produce an output? To make it clearer, I will re-edit my answer to include the contents of the script (I 'm currently unable to do so) and will inform you as soon as I do so. Thanks for your anticipated help.

Comment: Hello, I 've added the contents of the script file to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I 've reformatted the code again, it's well-presented now. Please could you help me out by considering what I earlier asked: ie with the 2 functions defined in the script and some arguments later provided for the second function, shouldn't it produce an output, instead of what it is currently producing? Thanks a lot for your anticipated assistance.

Comment: It should create one, view the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

You try to assign a variable with a tuple. To call your function just do this:

```
cat_twice(line1,line2)
```

This will call the function `cat_twice` and pass the arguments line1 and line2. If you do it like you did, you will create a var with a tuple in it, tuples are created like this: (tupleobj1, tupleobj2, etc), because of this your code didn't work

**Edit**

Here is a piece of code that is definitely working, you can use this:

```
def print_twice(var):
    print(var)
    print(var)

def combine_and_print(obj1, obj2):
    string = str(obj1) + str(obj2)
    print_twice(string)

line = 'bing'
line2 = 'tiddle'

combine_and_print(line, line2)
```

This workes, I've tried it out myself on python3. If it still doesn't work, I assume you have an spelling mistake in there or something like that.

Leave a like or an 'answer accepted' so I know if this is working, else just leave a comment I will review the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, that is I didn't call the function properly. However, I 've changed the line to cat_twice(line1,line2), but the script is still not generating any output, only the same RESTART message and nothing else. What could still be the problem?

Comment: To help me help you now, you need to tell me what output you expect. I think you want the things I edited to my 2nd answer

Comment: Like/answer accepted. Thanks a lot! You 've really made my day.But I  I still have a question. First of all, I simply copied your code and pasted it in a new script file and when I ran the script, it produced an output: it generated the script "bingtiddle" twice. My question is, please why did my amended script file  still not work? Was it simply that the code was somehow wrong? Or could it even be from the fact that the textbook was initially written for python2 and later re-modified for python 3 and thus my code might work for python 2 and not python 3?

Comment: Sorry I dont know that it might be a name Error, which was hdden or a simply typing error